# Get JSON response from a URL using JavaScript

Tags: javascript, json

The url http://smart-ip.net/geoip-json contains a JSON with data about your geolocation.

I want to store that JSON file in JavaScript variables, so I can work with the fields of this JSON.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It seems a cross-domain request. Directly read the JSON is problematic, but you can use JSONP. Your link supports it. You need something like this:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
  function your_callback(data) {
    // do something with data
    alert('City : '+data.city+' Country name : '+data.countryName);
  }
</script>

<script type="text/javascript" src="http://smart-ip.net/geoip-json?callback=your_callback"></script>​
```

[**DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/heera/gEWYH/).
`